# Bootstrap : Why is my col-md-6 not working?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have a little problem with my website. I want a responsive site, by using Bootstrap. In my mobile version the two columns need to be on top of each other, what is correct now. But, on my desktop version, the columns need to bo next to eachother. I thought col-md-6 was the right way to do this, but something went wrong... Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong.?

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #f2f6e9;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.tekstgeel{
  color: #d7a32d;
}

.tekstgroen{
  color: #4a7b45;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lijngeel{
  height:4px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #d7a32d;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.titel {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 18px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#profielfoto {
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.titel {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.ondertitel {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) {

.titel {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

.col-md-6 {
  border:1px solid black;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Lotte Pothé</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

      <div class="content">
               
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-10 col-md-12">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <h1 class="titel">Lotte Pothé<br>
            Jouw grafisch ontwerper<br>
             voor <span class="tekstgroen">digitaal en drukwerk</span></h1>
            <span class="lijngeel"></span><br>
            <h1 class="titel"><span class="tekstgeel">zakelijk en particulier</span></h1>
            <p>Wil jij je onderscheiden met jouw bedrijf.?<br> Ik ben namelijk gek van enthousiaste personen en plannen, dus ik luister graag naar jouw verhaal en wensen.! Ik sta open voor allerhande projecten, zowel groot als klein, dus bij twijfel contacteer mij gerust. Ben je geïnteresseerd in een samenwerking of heb je eerst nog enkele vragen.?
            </p>
            <a href="contact.html"> <p><span class="tekstgroen bold">Laat van je horen.!</span></p></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <img src="images/lotte.jpg" id="profielfoto" alt="Profielfoto Lotte Pothé">
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

I've putted a border around the .col-md-6 to show the width of them.

[image: desktop version]

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are unhelpful. Use the live demo feature of the question editor instead.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bootstrap-modal]? Pick *relevant* tags for your question.

Comment: Bro, plz bootstrap code on snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plz, add `div row class` between `two div columns`.

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.! Indeed, this works for my code, and was what I needed.